# How to run Multiple Tasks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, task

I want to process multiple tasks in **MatLab** simultaneously.

**For example:**

*I want to make two different analysis at the same time. Presently I open two instances of MATLAB".*

I was wondering if there is anyway to accomplish this using one instance of **MatLab**--*one MatLab window*?

Comment: check out running each one of them on a different worker
http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading...

[Instructables Tutorial Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Matlab-Multithreading-EASY/)

Also check out how to better utilize multi-cores via this matlab article dealing with Built-in Multithreading and Parallelism Using MATLAB Workers.

[Math Works Explanation Here](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the parallel toolbox of MATLAB.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/?s_cid=sol_compbio_sub2_relprod4_parallel_computing_toolbox